# PowerShell Invoke() function doesn't respond after few attempts

Tags: c#, powershell

**I don't know what is wrong with below code.**

Initially it works fine for few times. Then gradually the target server against which it is running, becomes unresponsive (I can't even login to that server unless I reboot it). When I try debugging the code the execution pointer doesn't return from below line, it disappears after entering below line:

```
Result = ps.Invoke();
```

Here is the complete code:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Run PowerShell Script code provided as input
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ScriptCode">
        /// Multiline script code provided as text input 
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// Collection of PSObject
        /// </returns>
        public Collection<PSObject> ExecutePowerShellScript(string ScriptCode)
        {
            Collection<PSObject> Result;

            try
            {
                RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();

                using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration))
                {
                    runspace.Open();

                    using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
                    {
                        ps.Runspace = runspace;
                        ps.Commands.AddScript(ScriptCode);

                        Result = ps.Invoke();

                        runspace.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string Error = ex.Message.ToLower().Contains("inner exception") ? ex.InnerException?.Message : ex.Message;
                PSObject errorObject = new PSObject();
                errorObject.Properties.Add(new PSNoteProperty("Error", Error));
                Result = new Collection<PSObject> { errorObject };
            }

            return Result;
        }
```

I have to restart the target server after every few days since it becomes unresponsive. I suspect something is wrong with above code. Can someone please suggest?

**EDIT:** Script code which is passed to this function

```
            ScriptCode = $@"
$Results, $ScheduledTask, $ScheduledTaskInfo = $null
$TaskName = ""{TaskName}""
Try
{{
    $Credentials = [pscredential]::new('domain\{SCORCHUName}', (ConvertTo-SecureString -String '{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SCORCHPwd")}' -AsPlainText -Force -ErrorAction Stop))
    $CIMSession = New-CimSession -Name TaskStatusCheck -ComputerName {ChangeMonitoringService_ServerName} -Credential $Credentials -ErrorAction Stop
    $ScheduledTask = Get-ScheduledTask -CimSession $CIMSession -TaskName $TaskName -ErrorAction Stop
    $ScheduledTaskInfo = Get-ScheduledTask -CimSession $CIMSession -TaskName $TaskName -ErrorAction Stop | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo

    if($ScheduledTask -ne $null -and $ScheduledTaskInfo -ne $null)
    {{
        $Results = [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{{ 
                        TriggerEnabled = $ScheduledTask.Triggers[0].Enabled
                        JobName = $ScheduledTask.TaskName
                        JobState = $ScheduledTask.State
                        LastJobResult = $ScheduledTaskInfo.LastTaskResult
                        LastRunTime = $ScheduledTaskInfo.LastRunTime
                        NextRunTime = $ScheduledTaskInfo.NextRunTime
                    }}
    }}
}}
Catch
{{
    $Results = [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{{ 
                        TriggerEnabled = $false
                        JobName = ""Error: $($Error[0].Exception.Message)""
                        JobState = ""Error""
                        LastJobResult = 0
                        LastRunTime = [Datetime]::MinValue
                        NextRunTime = [Datetime]::MinValue
                    }}
}}
Finally
{{
    Try
    {{
        (Get-CimSession -Name TaskStatusCheck -ErrorAction Stop).Close()
        (Get-CimSession -Name TaskStatusCheck -ErrorAction Stop).Dispose()
    }}
    Catch {{}}
    $Results
}}
";
```

Comment: Sounds like a memory leak. Try removing objects with `.Dispose()` on the runspace you create and possibly also on `ps` in a `finally {..}` block. We also have no idea what is contained in the PowerShell `ScriptCode`. That may keep consuming memory aswell..

Comment: The script is already taking care of disposing the objects. However I suspect the C# code may be leaving some thread open on the remote server. How can we identify the corresponding process on the target server?
I can still query the remote server through PowerShell commands while it is in hung state. It just doesn't allow me to login through RDB but it is a web server which is still working for other functions.

Comment: Added the script code in the question

Comment: Can someone please help me with the Process name under which this code may be running on target server when we remotely execute script using `Result = ps.Invoke();`